# How can I relay data between Chrome Extension and .NET (WPF/C#) via WCF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wcf, google-chrome

First off I have to say programming is not my strong point but I'm working on a project that does not need to be elegant, it just needs to work.

I have three parts to this, a Chrome Extension, a WPF application and a WCF service. I need to POST/GET data between the Chrome Extension and the WPF application. For simplicity sake, I have a variable that needs to be updated real-time in my WPF application from the Chrome Extension that outputs JSON objects.

1) The WPF application and the WCF are now two different projects in the same solution. I am not quite sure how to merge this so I only need to startup one project. Or perhaps, should they even be merged? The variable to be updated is in the WPF application.

2) I'm not quite sure how to get the Chrome Extension and WCF to have a continuous stream of data between them.

3) Any advice would be great, feel free to ask any questions.

Cheers,
Josh

Comment: Hi, and welcome to stackoverflow. You may be better off posting your many questions individually, as this will enable people to answer them faster.

Answer (score 2):

A few thoughts:

- **The WPF and WCF applications should not be merged into the same project** but depending on your use case **the WCF service could be embedded into the WPF application** if the service only needs to exist whilst the desktop application is open.
- On a side note **you can start both projects at the same time** during development with multiple startup projects in your solution configuration.
- Think about your architecture. If the variable to be updated is in the WPF application then the WCF layer is mediating between the two. Bear this is mind.
- There are many ways to achieve a 'continuous' stream of data between a JavaScript application running in the browser and a Web Service. WCF does support persistent duplex communication although I doubt it would be easy to integrate with a JavaScript application. Another option would be to look at the various **web sockets** implementations. However, before you make this decision you need to clarify your requirements:

  - Is the flow of data one-way or two-way?
  - Does the WCF application need to call the JavaScript application?
  - What do you really mean by 'continuous stream of data'? Would regular polling be sufficient?

From the information you have provided and for simplicity's sake I would suggest having JavaScript call the WCF service when it has new data to send and then the WPF application polling the WCF service for any updates. I cannot tell whether or not this WCF service ought to be embedded in the WPF application though.